# Interrupted: errors during collection

Tags: pytest

Suddenly, Pytest is started failing with the following error `Interrupted: errors during collection` for no apparent reason. The tests were working and were not modified.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently, this happens only on Windows' Powershell. Running Pytest on Windows' CMD works as usual.